# Last part of the constraint on the next line

Tags: math-mode, align

I have the following constraint:

```
& r_{ik}^l + r_{jk}^l \le 1 + y_{ij} + y_{ji}  
&&( i,j \in V; k \in R; l = 1, \ldots, R_k: i<j, (i,j) \not\in TE) \\
```

The constraint is much too long. I have tried different methods to continue the constraint on the next line, but unfortunately it always moved the following constraints as well and also didn't output what i had in mind.

It's probably very simple, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You should take a look at the `optidef`  package, which is dedicated to the layout of optimisation problems.

Comment: How does this posting differ from [yesterday's posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646394/5001)?

Comment: It doesn't differ, i don't know what happened. 

i did it like this:

\begin{align}
& r_{ik}^l + r_{jk}^l \le 1 + y_{ij} + y_{ji}  
&&( i,j \in V; k \in R; l = 1, \ldots, R_k: i<j, (i,j) \not\in TE) \\ 
\end{align} 

With optidef I have the problem that "minimize" and "subject to" are in English and my thesis should be in German. As far as I found out, these two terms are hard coded in the optidef package. Does anyone have an idea how else I could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you show the first constraint in display math mode and the second constraint in inline math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots 
\[
r^l_{\!ik} + r^l_{\!jk} \le 1 + y_{ij} + y_{ji} 
\]
and $i<j$ and $(i,j) \not\in TE$ for all $i,j \in V$, $k \in R$, and $1\le l \le R_k$.
\end{document}
```